# Set error if document with same name already exists in database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an activity where user can create a new team. When user has given team name and country and presses saveTeambutton, the saveTeam should check if three conditions match: teamNameText is not empty and teamCountryText is not empty. these work as they should but the third one doesn't. I want to check if the team name given already exists in the database and if it does, give an error. I use cloud firestore. This condition does give an error, but doesn't stop the team from being created.

heres the relevant part of code:

```
 public void saveTeam(){
    final String teamNameText = teamName.getText().toString();
    final String teamCountryText = teamCountry.getText().toString();
    final String username = user.getDisplayName();

    if (teamNameText.isEmpty()){
        teamName.setError("Team name is required");
        teamName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }




    if (teamCountryText.isEmpty()){
        teamCountry.setError("Team country is required");
        teamCountry.requestFocus();
        return;
    }


    db.collection("Teams").document(teamNameText).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.getResult().exists()){
                teamName.setError("Team with same name already exists");
                teamName.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });


    db.collection("Users").document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
            if (documentSnapshot.get("User's team") == null){
                TeamMap data1 = new TeamMap(teamNameText, teamCountryText);
                db.collection("Teams").document(teamNameText).set(data1);
                //Need to add hash to teamNameText to prevent duplicates

                Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("username", username);
                db.collection("Teams").document(teamNameText).collection("TeamUsers").document(uid).set(data);
                Map<String, Object> data2 = new HashMap<>();
                data2.put("User's team", teamNameText);

                db.collection("Users").document(uid).set(data2).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already in a team", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So the problem lies in that I set the error from the inside of the cloud firestore get. method which doesn't stop the rest of the method from executing. How can I format the method in a way that the team does not get created if the team name already exists? Thank you.

Comment: If you want the team names to be unique, consider using them as the name of the document in Firestore. Doing this will make it a lot easier to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: But I'm already doing that, right? I'm saving my documents with the team name and then in the saveTeam method I check if there is any document with the same team name. And this part of the code works perfectly. It's just that the error I'm setting doesn't stop the rest of the method from executing.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Sorry. In that case, I'd definitely try to do the validation in security rules instead of (or in addition to) in code.

Comment: Aside from that: move the code that depends on the check *into* the `onComplete` that it depends on.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Solved the problem

Comment: Perfect! Do you feel like posting a self-answer with the code of your solution? That gives nice closure to the question and is a great way to earn some reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the working code. I had to simply move the code that I want to execute after the states have been checked inside the onComplete.

this is the working saveTeam method that gets executed on button press:

```
 public void saveTeam(){
    final String teamNameText = teamName.getText().toString();
    final String teamCountryText = teamCountry.getText().toString();
    final String username = user.getDisplayName();

    if (teamNameText.isEmpty()){
        teamName.setError("Team name is required");
        teamName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (teamCountryText.isEmpty()){
        teamCountry.setError("Team country is required");
        teamCountry.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //Check if team with the same name already exists
    db.collection("Teams").document(teamNameText).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.getResult().exists()){
                teamName.setError("Team with same name already exists");
                teamName.requestFocus();

            }else{
                //If team with same name doesn't exist, save it
                db.collection("Users").document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();


                        //Check if user is already in a team
                        if (documentSnapshot.get("User's team") == null){
                            TeamMap data1 = new TeamMap(teamNameText, teamCountryText);
                            db.collection("Teams").document(teamNameText).set(data1);

                            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                            data.put("username", username);
                            db.collection("Teams").document(teamNameText).collection("TeamUsers").document(uid).set(data);
                            Map<String, Object> data2 = new HashMap<>();
                            data2.put("User's team", teamNameText);

                            db.collection("Users").document(uid).set(data2).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already in a team", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```